# React Native Redux triggering a real-time change on delete

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am building a React native social media app with Redux and Firebase/Firestore, and I need to implement a Following screen in which a user can see real-time who is he following.

I've managed to pull this off, get everything to work, except the deletion part. When a user is added in the redux store to the following list, and later removed, he is not removed.

The way I got this to work was the following: a listener on firestore collection, whenever a user is followed/unfollowed, he is added/removed successfully from the ***following*** State. Then, I have an action in Redux that, takes each id from following and gathers all the data of that user that is being followed into another State, ***followedUsers*** (on following state he only gets the id of the user, and with that id fetches data from the collection of users that is then dispatched to followedUsers state).

Below are the actions

```
export const followingState = () => {
return((dispatch) => {
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("following")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userFollowing")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            let following = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                return doc.id;
            })
            
            dispatch({type : FOLLOWING_STATE, following });
            
            for(let j = 0; j < following.length; j++){
                dispatch(followedUsersState(following[j]));
            };
        })
});
}; 




export const followedUsersState = (uid) => {

return((dispatch) => {
  
      
                firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("allUsers")
                .doc(uid)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    
                        let user =  {snapshot.id, ...snapshot.data()};
                       
                        dispatch({type : USERS_FOLLOWED_STATE, user});
                       
        });
})

}
```

Reducers also:

```
case FOLLOWING_STATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            following: action.following
       };


case FOLLOWED_USERS_STATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            followedUsers: [...state.followedUsers, action.user]
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in your "FOLLOWED_USERS_STATE" action reducer, by calling `followedUsers:[...state.followedUsers,action.user]` you are keeping the old state of `followedUsers` and adding new users every time your  `.collection("userFollowing").onSnapshot(...)` fires, i think you should try dispatching USERS_FOLLOWED_STATE with users array in one go, this way you are refreshing the whole array, i hope this can help

```
    export const followingState = () => {
    return((dispatch) => {
            firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("following")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userFollowing")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                let following = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    return doc.id;
                })
                
                dispatch({type : FOLLOWING_STATE, following });


                // get all users data from db in one go
                const proms = following.map((id)=>{
                    return getFollowedUserState(id)
                })

                
                Promise.all(proms).then((snapshots)=>{
                    
                    const users = snapshots.map((snapshot)=>{
                        return {id:snapshot.id, ...snapshot.data()};
                    })
                    
                    // set all users data to local state in one go
                    dispatch({type : USERS_FOLLOWED_STATE, users});
                })
                
            })
    });
    }; 

    
    const getFollowedUserState = (uid)=>{
        return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("allUsers")
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
    }


 case FOLLOWING_STATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            following: action.following
       };
    case FOLLOWED_USERS_STATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            followedUsers: action.users
        };
```